# Nesting Array by Value in Row

Tags: php, arrays, nested

Suppose I have an array like bellow. The second value in the array is the level/depth.

```
$arr = array(
    ['product 1', 0],
    ['product 2', 1],
    ['product 3', 1],
    ['product 4', 2],
    ['product 5', 0]
);
```

To represent it visually:

```
product 1
   product 2
   product 3
      product 4
product 5
```

I am trying to convert it into this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => product 1
            [1] => 0
            [children] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => product 2
                            [1] => 1
                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => product 3
                            [1] => 1
                            [children] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => product 4
                                    [1] => 2
                                )
                        )
                )
        )
    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => product 5
            [1] => 0
        )

)
```

With unlimited levels.

I have been banging my head against the wall with this for almost the entire day and I didn't even come close to the solution. As frustrating as it is not to be able to solve things on my own I have to admit defeat. I have no useful code to show. I know this is basically asking for code but this is beyond my brain power.
If anyone is up for a little challenge this might be it :) . I'd be very thankful.

Thank you.

Comment: Only thing I don't understand is: `Array
        (
            [0] => product 5
            [1] => 1
        )` why is the value of the second element 1 here? Typo? Also what should it represent anyway? The depth?

Comment: This records from database or its a random? Do you have an id for each record?

Comment: what if the initial array would be `$arr = array( ['product 5', 0],
    ['product 2', 2],
    ['product 4', 1],
    ['product 3', 2],
    ['product 1', 0] );` ? How should look the expected "transformation" output in such case?

Comment: @Rizier123 Yeah, as I said it represents the level/depth.

Comment: @Veniamin The records will be from a .csv file. Yes there are ids too actually.

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest That wouldn't be possible actually. Because in your example the first row has a depth 0 and the second one depth 2. I will never get that kind of input.

Comment: Just looked at your expected output again and found some few inconsistencies: Why is product 2 in a separate array? and not as the first one directly as array element? Why doesn't have product 3 "children" as key?

Comment: @Rizier123 It's not in a separate array, it's in an array with product 3. Product 3 has separate children.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've extended the initial array with one more level to meet your requirement - *"With unlimited levels."*
And here is solution with recursive function which I called `findParent`:

```
$arr = array(
    ['product 1', 0],
    ['product 2', 1],
    ['product 3', 1],
    ['product 4', 2],
    ['product 5', 3],
    ['product 6', 3],
    ['product 7', 0],
    ['product 8', 1],
);

$structure = [];
foreach ($arr as $k => $v) {
    if (empty($structure) || $v[1] == 0) {
        $structure[] = $v;
    } else {
        $last = array_pop($structure);
        $current_key = $k;
        $parent_key = "";

        while (--$current_key) {
            if ($v[1] > $arr[$current_key][1]) {
                $parent_key = $arr[$current_key][0];
                break;
            }
        }

        if ($v[1] == 1) {
            (isset($last['children']))? $last['children'][] = $v : $last['children'] = [$v];
        } else {
            findParent($last['children'], $parent_key, $v);
        }
        array_push($structure, $last);
    }
}

function findParent(&$el = [], $parent_key = "", $child = []){
    foreach ($el as &$v) {
       if ($v[0] == $parent_key) {
           (isset($v['children']))? $v['children'][] = $child : $v['children'] = [$child];
           break;
       } elseif (isset($v['children'])) {
           findParent($v['children'], $parent_key, $child);
       }
    }    
}

print_r($structure);
```

The output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => product 1
            [1] => 0
            [children] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => product 2
                            [1] => 1
                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => product 3
                            [1] => 1
                            [children] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => Array
                                        (
                                            [0] => product 4
                                            [1] => 2
                                            [children] => Array
                                                (
                                                    [0] => Array
                                                        (
                                                            [0] => product 5
                                                            [1] => 3
                                                        )

                                                    [1] => Array
                                                        (
                                                            [0] => product 6
                                                            [1] => 3
                                                        )
                                                )
                                        )
                                )
                        )
                )
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => product 7
            [1] => 0
            [children] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => product 8
                            [1] => 1
                        )
                )
        )
)
```

Comment: Hey, thank you for your efforts! There is one big problem though. Try to put in this array: $arr = array(
    ['product 1', 0],
    ['product 2', 1],
    ['product 3', 1],
    ['product 4', 2],
    ['product 5', 3],
    ['product 6', 3],
    ['product 7', 0],
    ['product 8', 1]
);
'product 5' and 'product 6' should be siblings like 'product 2' and 'product 3' are.

Comment: @Ivannnnn, I wouldn't call it "a big problem". See my update

Comment: Fantastic! Thanks a lot Roman, you saved my ass. That's exactly what I was trying to achieve for probably about 12 hours and couldn't lol. Out of curiosity, how long does it take you to write something like this?

Comment: Any idea why it only goes till level 10 ?

Answer (score 0):

I think better structure of input will be (if you have an id):

```
$arr = array(
  ['id' => 1, 'name' => 'product 1', 'cid' => 0, 'level' => 0],
  ['id' => 2, 'name' => 'product 2', 'cid' => 1, 'level' => 1],
  ['id' => 3, 'name' => 'product 3', 'cid' => 2, 'level' => 2],
  ['id' => 4, 'name' => 'product 4', 'cid' => 3, 'level' => 3],
  ['id' => 5, 'name' => 'product 5', 'cid' => 0, 'level' => 0]
);
```

where cid - id of parent item

```
$tree = [];
foreach($arr as $item){
    $tree[ $item['level'] ][ $item['cid'] ][] = $item;
} unset($item);
```

Recursive function to output tree

```
function echoTree($tree, $level = 0, $parent = 0, $prefix = ''){
    $level = intval($level);
    $parent= intval($parent);

    if(isset($tree[ $level ][ $parent ])){
        foreach($tree[ $level ][ $parent ] as $item){
            echo "{$prefix}{$item['name']}";
            echoTree($tree, $level + 1, $item['id'], $prefix.'---');
        }
    }
}
```

Try it, but i didn't test it

Comment: No, don't think that's what I'm looking for. Will take a closer look tomorrow with a fresh mind. Yeah, might be easier if I introduce a parent id first. I didn't downvote BTW.